# Install ARM Translation (libhoudini) on official Android Emulator

Tags: android, arm

I have a small application that uses a native ARM shared library (`.so`). When using Genymotion, I can successfuly install the ARM translation package (just by dropping the ZIP file) and the app runs fine on a x86-based emulator.

Now I have the need to run the same app in a headless linux server, which is not supported by Genymotion. I downloaded the official google emulator and corresponding system image. After extracting the files from zip archive and uploading to `/system` partition, I can run `houdini --version`, however the application won't install (`INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS`).

Can you please guide me how to run the app which contains ARM library on the official google x86 emulator?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 2):

What is the output of houdini --version ?

When you install applications PackageManager checks ABI of the app(which libraries are contained in the apk .so files) and the ABI of the system (which type of libraries system supports)

if you run `getprop | grep -i abi`

```
getprop | grep -i abi
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [x86]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: []
```

In this output, the system supports 32 bit .so files of x86, armeabi-v7a and armeabi type.

Please check this output on your device. Most probably there will be no mention of armeabi in this output.

So when PackageManager tries to install ARM app and checks that this ABI is not supported, it throws `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` error.

So you will have to fix the system ABIs. 
Edit the file `/system/build.prop` to add ARM support, in `ro.product.cpu.abilist and ro.product.cpu.abilist32`.
If you are running 64 bit Android, you will have to change these lines.

```
ro.product.cpu.abilist=x86_64,x86,arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=x86_64,arm64-v8a
```